# Rationale of the SHA-256 sigma function definitions

Tags: sha-256, shs

When the sigma functions are defined in equations (4.4) and (4.5) in [FIPS PUB 180-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf#page=15), the defined functions show the traditional sigma summation symbol, with limits 0 to {256} and 1 to {256}. The definitions, however, are in terms of circular right shift and XOR operations. Why is a summation symbol used here?

Comment: I'm reading the {256} as meaning _for SHA-256_ (and derivatives).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the naming of functions and the functions are already defined - rotations (ROTR) and x-ors ($\oplus$). There are two $\Sigma$ and $\sigma$ functions for SHA-256 and SHA-512 series. And, in Greek, the $\Sigma$ is capital of $\sigma$.

The upper index represents the SHA family as 256 and 512. The sub-index, selects the function. $\Sigma_{0}^{\{256\}}$ means the first $\Sigma$ function of SHA-256 series. Note the curly braces.

Note: the functions are started to appear with SHA-2 series. It is not listed with SHA-1, the document can be seen from [archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/federalinformati1801nati#mode/2up)

Comment: So these indices are nothing to do with the traditional use of the sigma symbol for summation, then.

Comment: That is correct.